# Cleanest way to avoid branching with templates

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a cuda kernel which takes some `bool` template arguments which help to explicitly optimize out unused sections of the kernel. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner/more compact way of instantiating the kernel call than my solution below.

**Device Template**

```cpp
template <bool pred1, bool pred2>
__global__ void foo(args)
{
  /* probably doesn't need to exist, but just to improve readability in the kernel */
  constexpr bool predAll = pred1 && pred2;

  if (predAll || pred1 || pred2 || someVariablePred) {
  /* working hard */
  } else {
  /* or hardly working */
  }
}
```

**Working Host Code**

```cpp
const bool pred1 = variableCond1 == variableCond2, pred2 = variableCond3 == variableCond4;

/* working, compiles, but cumbersome */
for (int i = 0; i < bigNumber; ++i) {
  if (pred1) {
    if (pred2) {
      foo<true, true><<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(args...);
    }
    foo<true, false><<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(args...);
  } else if (pred2) {
    foo<false, true><<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(args...);
  } else {
    foo<false, false><<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(args...);
  }
}
```

**Want Something Clean Like This**

```cpp
/* doesn't compile */
const bool pred1 = variableCond1 == variableCond2, pred2 = variableCond3 == variableCond4;

for (int i = 0; i < bigNumber; ++i) {
  foo<pred1, pred2><<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(args...);
}
```

I understand why the second kernel launch won't compile since the predicates are not *explicity* written out/knowable at compile-time, but since there are a finite number of template argument combinations the information is *technically* all there at compile-time no?

Comment: No, templates are a compile time concept (they don't exist at runtime) and the compiler doesn't do any magic for you like generating all possible combinations and picking the right one at runtime.

Comment: you need to map the runtime conditions to the compile time template parameters somehow. Your working code is already rather clear and readable.

Comment: Another not on readability: The template actually reduced it, imo. If this is close to your real code then `foo` does one of two things. You could cover that with _one_ `if/else`. But this way you have the `if/else` inside `foo` _and_ 4 conditions to pick the right template. So...is it really worth it? Also, yes, the `predAll = pred1 && pred2` is completely redundant and confusing imo.

Comment: Unfortunately the real `foo` is significantly more complicated. `pred` and friends provide shortcuts through a couple of layers of branching within the kernel, most calling different device functions all of which also take `pred` and friends as template parameters.

Comment: I would say that the `if-else` chain in the "Working Host Code" should be encapsulated into its own function, but otherwise you already have the clean approach.

Comment: i remember similar questions, but don't find them anymore. What you can do is reduce complexity of the mapping from 2x2 (for `true/false x true/false`) to 2 + 2.

Comment: I would put your original code to godbolt, since I've got feeling compiler is able to optimize this more then you expect it. For example will move this conditions outside off loops. IMO you barking under wrong tree. Did you do a profiling before blaming this code?

Comment: Yes, profiling is what lead me to templatize it to begin with. To provide a bit more context, the main kernel (`foo`) runs a very tight memory-bound loop. The template arguments guarantee (if true) to the kernels that data is a multiple of some number, and therefore correctly aligned in memory for vectorized loads/stores. Without the template arguments kernels would need to compute on the fly with costly variable modulo's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are ways but they require more lines than your current implementation. And I'm not sure if the following implementation improves readability more than just putting your 'unclean' section in a separate function.

The following code is probably longer than it will be for you because I implemented two ways (calling directly and getting a function pointer) and two examples to show it really works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <bool pred0, bool pred1, bool pred2, bool pred3, bool pred4>
void Func1()
{
  std::cout << "func1: " << pred0 << pred1 << pred2 << pred3 << pred4 << std::endl;
}

template <bool pred0, bool pred1, bool pred2, bool pred3, bool pred4>
struct Func1Wrapper
{
  static constexpr auto Ptr = Func1<pred0, pred1, pred2, pred3, pred4>;
  static void Call()
  {
    Func1<pred0, pred1, pred2, pred3, pred4>();
  }
};

template <bool pred0, bool pred1, bool pred2>
void Func2()
{
  std::cout << "func2: " << pred0 << pred1 << pred2 << std::endl;
}

template <bool pred0, bool pred1, bool pred2>
struct Func2Wrapper
{
  static constexpr auto Ptr = Func2<pred0, pred1, pred2>;
  static void Call()
  {
    Func2<pred0, pred1, pred2>();
  }
};

template <template<bool...> class F, bool... preds>
struct Ct
{
  template <bool newPred>
  using Expanded = Ct<F, preds..., newPred>;

  static void CallFunc()
  {
    F<preds...>::Call();
  }

  static auto GetFunc()
  {
    return F<preds...>::Ptr;
  }
};

template <class DeducedPreds, typename BoolLast>
void Rt2Ct(BoolLast predLast)
{
  if (predLast)
    DeducedPreds::template Expanded<true>::CallFunc();
  else
    DeducedPreds::template Expanded<false>::CallFunc();
}

template <class DeducedPreds, typename BoolFirst, typename ...BoolRest>
void Rt2Ct(BoolFirst predFirst, BoolRest... predRest)
{
  if (predFirst)
    Rt2Ct<typename DeducedPreds::template Expanded<true>, BoolRest...>(predRest...);
  else
    Rt2Ct<typename DeducedPreds::template Expanded<false>, BoolRest...>(predRest...);
}

template <template<bool...> class F, typename ...Bools>
void FuncCaller(Bools... preds)
{
  Rt2Ct<Ct<F>, Bools...>(preds...);
}

template <class DeducedPreds, typename BoolLast>
auto Rt2CtGet(BoolLast predLast)
{
  if (predLast)
    return DeducedPreds::template Expanded<true>::GetFunc();
  else
    return DeducedPreds::template Expanded<false>::GetFunc();
}

template <class DeducedPreds, typename BoolFirst, typename ...BoolRest>
auto Rt2CtGet(BoolFirst predFirst, BoolRest... predRest)
{
  if (predFirst)
    return Rt2CtGet<typename DeducedPreds::template Expanded<true>, BoolRest...>(predRest...);
  else
    return Rt2CtGet<typename DeducedPreds::template Expanded<false>, BoolRest...>(predRest...);
}

template <template<bool...> class F, typename ...Bools>
auto FuncGetter(Bools... preds)
{
  return Rt2CtGet<Ct<F>, Bools...>(preds...);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FuncCaller<Func1Wrapper>(std::stoi(argv[1]), std::stoi(argv[2]), std::stoi(argv[3]), std::stoi(argv[4]), std::stoi(argv[5]));
  auto f2 = FuncGetter<Func2Wrapper>(std::stoi(argv[1]), std::stoi(argv[3]), std::stoi(argv[5]));
  f2();
  return 0;
}
```

The code requires C++14 (C++11 should be possible with a little rewrite) and is CUDA free because I don't really see how calling a kernel instead of a normal function changes the problem. Of course you would have to add a few parameters for passing `dimGrid` and `dimBlock` and all the `args` you need.
As it already has been noted you may want to put the `if-else` stuff outside of the `for` loop. That is why I also implemented the `FuncGetter` routine.
Also note that you may want to ensure that the `Bools`, `BoolFirst`, etc template arguments really are of type `bool`.

Compilation, function call and output:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp && ./a.out 1 0 1 0 0
func1: 10100
func2: 110
```